# Some people get 403 Forbidden, most do not?

Tags: web-hosting

Some people and services receive a mysterious 403 forbidden page when surfing to my website https://rauch.io, e.g., when trying to use https://onlinecurl.com/ to curl my page it succeeds, obtaining a 403 error page.

However, if I visit the page with my browser (even in incognito mode - so definitely not "logged in") it returns 200 just fine.

What is the problem? I'm all out of ideas.

Note: between my web server and my page is a free Cloudflare service if that could be the problem.

Comment: I just try and I get a 403 with Firefox. check your error logs to see if there is something

Comment: And the redirect is strange : https ://rauch.io -> http(withoutS)://www.rauch.io -> https ://www.rauch.io/. Why returning to non secured connection ?

Comment: @Dom: I receive "client denied by server configuration" error log entries ... but I can't find out why .... all my browsers show the page just fine :-/

Comment: At least the redirect problem should now be gone - can you confirm this?

Comment: @Dom: It must have to do with the client IP range somehow ... using https://www.croxyproxy.com the page loads just fine. Is it doing so for you as well?

Comment: What is your Apache configuration, then?

Comment: I'm using a shared web hoster, so I unfortunately don't know my Apache configuration...

Comment: @D.R : Redirect are now OK. But I think you filter by IP somewhere. If we come by cloudflare, we are rejected. When you try directely, the page should be OK.